different values when calculating definite integrals using python
One way of calculating definite integrals is using finite difference methods. I have two ways:
function1:
def function1(f, dx, a, b):
    g=0
    while a<b:
        g=g + dx*f(a)
        a=a + dx
    return g

function2:
def function2(f, dx, a, b):
    g=0
    while a<b-dx*0.1:
        g=g + dx*f(a)
        a=a + dx
    return g

If we calculate it for (xx, *0.001,0,11), each value is 443.727 and 443.606. (small number is omitted)
For (x*x,0.001,0,12), each value is 576.072 and 575.928. (small number is omitted)
My questions are:

Which is better?
Why are they different values?

Actually for (x\**x*\*.001,0,1),  each value is same number. It is 0.3328375.(small number is omitted)
Also for (x*x, 0.001,0,1) each value is same number. It is 333328.(small number is omitted)

Please [edit] your post to just present the information you have. Don't write one thing, then in the same post also say something else at the end: just edit the text so that your question accurately reflects the situation you are in. And if that situation changes, you update the post again.

The number are differant because you told the program to stop at different places.
If I tell you to go East, and stop before you get to #100, you will stop at a different place than if I tell you to go East, and stop after you get to #100.
Then you call me and tell me the street number where you stopped: In one case you tell me #98. In the other, you tell me #102. The two numbers are different.

Both of your methods are wrong at the end points (the second one with a fence post error much more so than the first as pointed out above).
The Trapezium method for definite integrals is simplest but gives poor results. The only time when it is justified to use it is integrating noisy experimental data with no guarantee of smoothness. It can be improved by various tricks like Richardson extrapolation but it is usually not worth the effort.
Also the end points f(a) and f(b) in your integration should be weighted down by a factor of 2. Draw a diagram for N=3 dx = (b-a)/3 to see why (only half their area is included inside the range of integration). Alternatively you can evaluate at f(a+dx/2) etc. The simplest modification to your source would be:
def function3(f, dx, a, b):
    g= dx*(f(a) + f(b))/2  
    a = a + dx
    while a<b-dx:
       g=g + dx*f(a)
       a=a + dx
    return g

I have left the code as close to the original as possible, but it is worth noting that the dx* can be moved outside the loop as return dx*g.
Generally it is better to ask an integrator to divide the interval into N and compute dx = (b-a)/N in the integration routine since otherwise users can feed it inconsistent values for dx that lead to trouble near b.
There is another minor technicality that a = a + dx will accumulate rounding error for some commonly used obvious choices of dx, 0.1 and powers thereof perform badly in this respect. Having a loop counter N and computing N*dx avoids this.
The simplest integration method that has reasonable accuracy is Simpson's rule which makes a parabolic interpolation of the points that you compute the function at. It isn't all that much more complex and gives a very much better result on smooth functions for almost the same computational effort.
